# Pdf coversion using Microsoft graph api

Tags: pdf, microsoft-graph-api, standards, pdf-conversion

Is it possible to convert docs to pdf/a standard pdf.
In VB, useISO19005_1 Boolean
true to limit PDF usage to the PDF subset standardized as ISO 19005-1; otherwise, false. If you set this parameter to true, the resulting files are more reliably self-contained but may be larger or show more visual artifacts due to the restrictions of the format. The default is false.

Any possible way in graph api? I need Pdf/a(ISO-19005-1) standard pdf. Could you please help me in doing so

Thanks.

Comment: You can convert a document to PDF using [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Please see if this can help you.

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity unfortunately that Graph API does not produce PDF/A documents. You can validate that using the tool provided by [veraPDF](https://verapdf.org/home/)

Comment: Thank you Shiva and DelGurth.. Can you please suggest me best api which can convert any doc format to pdf/a standard pdf format...scalable and reliable one.

Comment: Unfortunately I've not found one yet. I came across your question in search for an answer on the same question, and saw the remark by @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, which is unfortunately invalid.

Comment: @DelGurth - If you talk about document to 'generic' PDF and it works with Microsoft Graph API as updated earlier. Being said that, i remember the feature request item/ [Microsoft uservoice item](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40068832-make-it-possible-to-create-pdf-a), please go ahead and upvote it; so that it can be considered and implement it.

Comment: Does the above helped?